# getting index of element in list (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

Didn't understand why getting index of elements in list works differnt in next examples:

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 4]

print list.index(list[3])
```

Returns expected 3 as index fourth element in list

but

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 1]

print list.index(list[3])
```

Unexpectedly returns 0.

What the difference? It's python 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.index(x)` always returns index of first match. In first case first match is at index 3  i.e., 4 is at index 3, while in second case first match is at index 0 i.e, 1 is at index 0. 1 is also at indices 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.index(x)
>
> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

You are returning the index of the first match.

Answer (score 0):

1st using list as variable name is bad practice:

```
index search the element from the start of list, so in here you will get always 0:
>>> my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1]  
>>> my_list.index(1)
0
>>> my_list.index(my_list[3])
0
```

Answer (score 0):

list.index(n) will return the index of the first 'n' in the 'list'.
So in your example

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 1] #list[3] will equal 1
```

so `list.index([3])` or `list.index(1)` will return 0, or the index of the first 1 in the list.